# How to connect an oracle 11g database and php

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm working on a university assignment where I am trying to work with PHP and Oracle 11g database. I've downloaded Oracle 11g in to my PC, and I'm actually accessing the databases I made at university I am also able to use the service name, hostname and SID set by my university.
However, what I'm slightly puzzled by is how can I work with Oracle database and PHP? I have XAMP installed in my PC which enables me to work with MySQL and PHP, but was wondering If I can also use this with oracle.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Try the underground PHP and Oracle manual here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

From the "Who should read this book" section

> This book is designed to bridge the gap between the many PHP and the
>   many Oracle texts available. It shows how to use the PHP scripting
>   language with the Oracle database, from installation to using them
>   efficiently.
>
> The installation and database discussion in this book highlights the
>   Oracle Database 10g Express Edition, but everything covered in this
>   book also applies to the other editions of the Oracle database,
>   including Oracle Database 11g. The PHP you write for Oracle Database
>   10g Express Edition can be run, without change, against all editions
>   of the Oracle database as well.
>
> The book contains much unique material on PHP's Oracle OCI8 and
>   PDO_OCI extensions. It also incorporates several updated installation
>   guides previously published on the Oracle Technology Network web site.

There is also an tutorial of connecting PHP with Oracle here http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm

and some further tutorials in the Oracle+PHP cookbook here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/index-091900.html